# If singularity points are dense in some circle, does the circle necessarily natural boundary?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=0}z^{2^k}=z+z^2+z^4+z^8+\dots$  has radius of
> convergence $1$. Yet as $z\to z_0$, where $z_0$ is any $2^n$th root of
> unity, all the terms of the power series past $z^{2^n}$ approach $1$,
> so that $f(z)\to \infty$. Hence $f$ is singular at every $2^n$th root
> of unity, $n\geq 1$. Since these are dense on the unit circle, that
> circle is a natural boundary for the power series.

Can you explain the last sentence? I understand that the points consisting of every $2^n$th root of unity where $n$ is an arbitrary $\mathbb{N}$ is dense in circle but natural boundary demands that they are ALL points on the circle, which is obviously not true.

Comment: Points of regularity are open pretty much by definition (analytic extension requires open set) so the points of singularity are closed hence if dense they are full circle; a power series can converge everywhere on the boundary (and even all its derivatives for that matter) and still have the circle as natural boundary so regularity at a point on the boundary is a very strong condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of natural boundary is incorrect. It is a natural boundary since one cannot analytically continue $f$ beyond the unit circle. This is easy to see, pick any point outside the unit circle and any neighborhood around that point which intersects the unit disk. Then that neighborhood contains a singularity by density.

See, for instance, [this link](https://planetmath.org/naturalboundary).

Comment: In the textbook, it says that "If $f(z)=\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=0}a_nz^n$ has a singularity at every point on its circle of convergence, then that circle is called a natural boundary of $f$."

Comment: Can't help you there buddy, your book seems to contradict itself. What's the textbook?

Comment: It's Bak Newman's Complex Analysis. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I don't think the book contradicts itself.  The authors are expecting you to see that if there is a dense subset consisting of singular points, then every point on the circle is singular.  Indeed, how could there be a regular point on the circle, since every neighborhood of it contains a singular point?